# Getting target IDs from promotions related to an order item

Tags: java

I have a awful code with a big cyclomatic complexity. I have tried different variants, but haven't had good result. Please, help me to refactor this code:

```
public Set<String> getTargetIdsFromPromotion(String itemToRefundId, RepositoryItem orderItem) {
    Set<String> result = new HashSet<String>();
    List<RepositoryItem> relationships = getRelationships(orderItem);
    for (RepositoryItem relationship : relationships) {
        if (isValidShippingType(relationship)) {
            List<RepositoryItem> adjustments = getAdjustments(relationship);
            for (RepositoryItem adjustment : adjustments) {
                RepositoryItem promotion = getPromotion(adjustment);
                if (promotion != null){
                    Set<String> targetIds = getTargetIdsByQualifier(itemToRefundId, promotion);
                    if (!targetIds.isEmpty()) {
                        return targetIds;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return new HashSet<String>();
}
```

Comment: You should have just one return statement.  If you change return targetIds; to result = targetIds; or use result = getTargetIdsByQualifier(itemToRefundId, promotion); instead of creating targetIds, you should be able to use your editor to refactor the code.

Comment: The simple answer: follow the single layer of abstraction principle. Basically you turn each *block* in there ... into its own private method. Might sound crazy, but when you get used to it, you will loathe at code like this what has 5 nesting levels in one method.

Comment: And finally: i wouldnt return a new Hashset for "nothing found" - return Collections.emptySet() instead (unless the caller starts adding things to the set coming back).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the java 8 stream API:

```
public Set<String> getTargetIdsFromPromotion(String itemToRefundId, RepositoryItem orderItem) {
    return getRelationships(orderItem).stream()
            .filter(this::isValidShippingType)
            .map(this::getAdjustments)
            .flatMap(Collection::stream)
            .map(this::getPromotion)
            .filter(Objects::nonNull)
            .map(p -> getTargetIdsByQualifier(itemToRefundId, p))
            .filter(s -> !s.isEmpty())
            .findFirst()
            .orElseGet(Collections::emptySet);
}
```

Comment: `.flatMap(this::getAdjustments)` - doesn't this method (`flatMap`) expect the function to return a stream? So actually it should be `.flatMap(relationship -> getAdjustments(relationship).stream())`

Comment: @smac89 you are quite right. I implemented your suggestion in a IMHO cleaner way though. Thx